# missing integration services project template SSDT

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

Ive just bought VS 2015(14.0.25431.01 update3) and installed SSDT (14.0.61021.0) but cant find the template for SISS anywhere. Cant find the BI-folder either.
Been googling around for hours but only find that earlier versions had problem and the solution would be to install the latest version.
Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Apologies for the silly question, but just want to verify -- when installing the SSDT update, I assume that you did check the box to install the SSIS components?

Comment: I must re-check that...just to be sure.
but Another question...do I need to run SSDT on the sql server? or can I use it on my dev-computer?

Comment: Your dev-computer is the best place to run it. =^)

Comment: So I thought :)
Reinstalled it and cant find anywhere any box that I havnt checked.

Comment: after repairing the SSDT and restart of computer I now see it. Wierd, but as long as it works :)